# Need help in debugging my android-java code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Log cat shows "Runtime exception - cant create handler inside  thread that has not called looper.prepare??I want to send location update of my phone to some other phone via sms after a fixed interval of time.Please help . Suggest ways to save power also

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 b1  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1 );
 t1 = new Timer();
 t2 = new Timer();
 lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 listener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
         String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()             );
        String number = "5556";
        sm.sendTextMessage(number,null,message,null,null);
    }
};
```

Schedule request update after every fixed interval

t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, listener,null);
    }
},0,300000);

}

}
```

Comment: **cant create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare** would have been a better title for the question

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear from the [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) documentation, but I suspect each task runs on its own thread. Also, the documentation for the [LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29) call you’re using says “If looper is null then the callbacks will be called on the main thread”, but I suspect this is wrong, because it disagrees with the one with the alternative signature, which says “If looper is null then the callbacks will be called on the current thread”. If the latter is correct, that would explain your problem, because you are calling `requestSingleUpdate` within your `TimerTask` thread, which has no `Looper`.

Perhaps use the result from [getMainLooper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getMainLooper%28%29) instead of `null` for the last arg to `requestSingleUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

That error basically means "You are trying to do something in a background thread that you are not allowed to do in a background thread.

Your listener will handle the asynchronous nature of the location request. You do not need to thread it.

If you DO need things threaded, read up on [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).